# Composite iterator with queue

Tags: c#, .net, composite

I have a tree structure with events and as soon as an event fires I´d like to match that event at the current tree level, dequeue it and wait for the next event and match it against the underlying level. Im having a hard time wrapping this up in my head..Im just sitting here stairing like a zombie.

Is the composite pattern the right choice here or should I do something completly different?

/Mike

Comment: Your tree is already a composite.

Comment: We're having a hard time imagining this too without seeing your code and an example of what you mean.